# Get level of items in a nested list

Tags: python, graph, tree, nested-lists

**Problem:**

I have some linked data and I want to build a structure like this one on this picture :

[image: my structure]

and get the level of each item because in the future I will make some calculations by staring at the lowest level of my tree structure.

**Expected Result:**

I need to get a structure that gives me items per level :

- level 0: A
- level 1: A = B, C,D
- level 2: D = E, F, G
- level 3: E =  H,I , J, K

**what I have tried so far:**

I've tried this recursive code to simulate the behavior but I'm unable to get items the level of items.

```
dict_item = {"A": ["B","C","D"], "D": ["E","F","G"], "E":["H","I","J"]}
def build_bom(product):
    if not dict_item.get(product):
        return product
    else :
        return [build_bom(x) for x in dict_item.get(product)]
print(build_bom("A"))
```

My output is a nested list like this :

```
['B', 'C', [['H', 'I', 'J'], 'F', 'G']]
```

**My Question:**

I'm not sure if this is the best approach to handle my problem.
And how to get the desired output?
here is the desired output :

```
[ {"parent_E":["H", "I", "J"]}, 
{"parent_D": ["E", "F", "G"]},
{"parent_A"} :["D","C","B"]},
]
```

A list of dictionaries ( where keys are parents and values are children), the first element in the list is the lowest level of my structure and the last is the highest element.

PS: This is a simulation but in future, I will have to works on large datasets with this code.
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: "And how to get the desired output?" you showed us your output but you never mentioned what is the "desired output". Your question is not clear, if your output is the desired output - what's wrong with the current approach ?

Comment: I see the section "expected result" but I don't see the actual *output* of the expected result.

Comment: Try: `[{"parent_" + k: v} for k, v in dict_item.items()]`

Comment: not sure about what ?

Comment: it give a result but it's not ordered per level, it just get item in the dict

Comment: That is what you asked for in "desired output" (other than the illegal item `{"parent_A"}` that is). If you want it in reverse order use: `.reverse()`

Comment: thanks for the interested , but i've added this explanation after the desired output : 
A list of dictionaries ( where keys are parents and values are children), the first element in the list is the lowest level of my structure and the last is the highest element.

Comment: what's your input data like? is it `dict_item`?

Comment: yes @LesterT. that is my input data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I will approach this problem. First, I'll generate the tree from your `dict_item` object.

```
dict_item = {"A": ["B","C","D"], "D": ["E","F","G"], "E":["H","I","J"]}

def build_tree(x):
    if x in dict_item:
        return {x: [build_tree(v) for v in dict_item[x]]}
    else:
        return x

tree = build_tree("A")
print(tree)
>>> {'A': ['B', 'C', {'D': [{'E': ['H', 'I', 'J']}, 'F', 'G']}]}
```

Then, do a breadth-first search on the tree. Each time we hit an element that has children, we append it to a list:

```
results = []
queue = [tree]

while queue:
    x = queue.pop(0)
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        parent, children = list(x.items())[0]
        results.append({'parent_' + parent: dict_item[parent]})
        for child in children:
            queue.append(child)

print(results)
>>> [{'parent_A': ['B', 'C', 'D']}, {'parent_D': ['E', 'F', 'G']}, {'parent_E': ['H', 'I', 'J']}]
```

Then all we need to do now, is to reverse the list:

```
print list(reversed(results))
>>> [{'parent_E': ['H', 'I', 'J']}, {'parent_D': ['E', 'F', 'G']}, {'parent_A': ['B', 'C', 'D']}]
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works as expected, even if don't understand how the BFS algo works

Comment: Isn't that DFS?

Comment: I've noticed that you have changed the code, what is the best approach (the most performent)for BFS the while solution or the recursive one?