# Find all instances of a particular item in a list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Lets say I have this list where few items are occurring more then once (items may be as list or dict inside a list.

```
list_1 = ['@BOOLOP : and', '@SEQ : 0', '@TYPE : 0', "BOOLOP : [{'@BOOLOP': 'or', '@SEQ': '1', '@TYPE': '0', 'FRAGMENT': [{'@FUNC1': 'value', '@FUNC2': 'literal', '@NULLACTION': 'Fragment is false', '@OP': '=', '@PROP1': 'PB:SALES_TYPE', '@PROP2': 'PURCHASE', '@SEQ': '1', '@TYPE': '1'}, {'@FUNC1': 'value', '@FUNC2': 'literal', '@NULLACTION': 'Fragment is false', '@OP': '=', '@PROP1': 'PB:SALES_TYPE', '@PROP2': 'LEASE', '@SEQ': '2', '@TYPE': '1'}]}, {'@BOOLOP': 'or', '@SEQ': '2', '@TYPE': '0', 'FRAGMENT': {'@FUNC1': 'value', '@FUNC2': 'list', '@NULLACTION': 'Fragment is false', '@OP': 'in', '@PROP1': 'PB:PRICELIST', '@PROP2': 'LeaseAccountingContracts', '@SEQ': '1', '@TYPE': '1'}}, {'@BOOLOP': 'or', '@SEQ': '4', '@TYPE': '0', 'FRAGMENT': [{'@FUNC1': 'value', '@FUNC2': 'propval', '@NULLACTION': 'Fragment is false', '@OP': '=', '@PROP1': 'PICK_SKU1', '@PROP2': '._sku', '@SEQ': '1', '@TYPE': '1'}, {'@FUNC1': 'value', '@FUNC2': 'propval', '@NULLACTION': 'Fragment is false', '@OP': '=', '@PROP1': 'PICK_SKU10', '@PROP2': '._sku', '@SEQ': '2', '@TYPE': '1'}]}]"]
```

The type of occurrence of that item can vary like sometimes it may be in the type list or dict.

```
 list_2 = ['@BOOLOP : and', '@SEQ : 0', '@TYPE : 0', {'@FUNC1': 'value', '@FUNC2': 'literal', '@NULLACTION': 'Fragment is false', '@OP': '=', '@PROP1': '_sku', '@PROP2': 'ZHD8', '@SEQ': '1', '@TYPE': '1'}]
```

What I am trying to achieve is get all the `@BOOLOP:and` and `@BOOLOP:or` along with the hierarchy. Like in the `list_1` the `@BOOLOP:and` has `or` in side of it. There may be instances where there are `@BOOLOP inside of a`@BOOLOP`or just two separate`@BOOLOP`

```
list_3 = ['@BOOLOP : and', '@SEQ : 0', '@TYPE : 0', "FRAGMENT : [{'@FUNC1': 'propval', '@FUNC2': 'literal', '@NULLACTION': 'Fragment is false', '@OP': '=', '@PROP1': '_amEntitled', '@PROP2': '1', '@SEQ': '1', '@TYPE': '1'}, {'@FUNC1': 'value', '@FUNC2': 'literal', '@NULLACTION': 'Fragment is false', '@OP': '=', '@PROP1': 'IsShipingSelected', '@PROP2': 'yes', '@SEQ': '2', '@TYPE': '1'}, {'@FUNC1': 'value', '@FUNC2': 'literal', '@NULLACTION': 'Fragment is false', '@OP': '=', '@PROP1': 'PB:BaseSystemSelected', '@PROP2': 'yes', '@SEQ': '3', '@TYPE': '1'}]", {'@BOOLOP': 'or', '@SEQ': '4', '@TYPE': '0', 'FRAGMENT': [{'@FUNC1': 'value', '@FUNC2': 'literal', '@NULLACTION': 'Fragment is false', '@OP': '=', '@PROP1': 'PB:SALES_TYPE', '@PROP2': 'PURCHASE', '@SEQ': '1', '@TYPE': '1'}, {'@FUNC1': 'value', '@FUNC2': 'literal', '@NULLACTION': 'Fragment is false', '@OP': '=', '@PROP1': 'PB:SALES_TYPE', '@PROP2': 'LEASE', '@SEQ': '2', '@TYPE': '1'}]}]
```

The whole point of getting them and there hierarchy is that I need to perform some operation on the Fragment tag associated with a respective `@BOOLOP`. Lets says there are 2 or may be three `FRAGMENT` items in a `@BOOLOP:or` condition and 1 in a `@BOOLOP:and` condition . I need to check whether the `AND` `OR` makes sense or not in order to move forward.

I came this far by first extracting this info from an XML(converted to json because I had some difficulties parsing it) and then converting it to JSON and then extracting the useful information from it. I am not able to figure out where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

This is my sample code where I am getting these lists. If you want the whole JSON please ask. But I feel this will give you the basic idea.

```
def getRuleProp(json_rule_data):
    target_rules = getTargetPickRules(json_rule_data)
    for x,y in target_rules.items():
        print(y)  # prints the sample lists I have posted
```

I have tried to get all the possible scenarios in image format:
[image: Scenario]

Comment: i suggest you try to reduce this problem a bit, try coming up with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Here's what first popped into my head: Whoa, this guy might need to write his own parser.

I don't have the time to go into all the details right now,
but here are some keywords and a link to get you started:

You'll need a Tokenizer (Lexer)
to feed a Parser and
parse your structure into an Abstract Syntax Tree

https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/

That might be total overkill though... ;)

Comment: @SebastianLoehner thanks for the help. I will surely have a try it out. Probably learn a thing or two in the process.

Comment: It's a truly fascinating topic... here's an example using `lark` http://blog.erezsh.com/how-to-write-a-dsl-in-python-with-lark/

Comment: Yes, at first I though maybe a BFS or DFS will do the work. I took some reference from this [lget-level-of-items-in-a-nested-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827745/get-level-of-items-in-a-nested-list). But this isn't of any help